# scala generic function to convert "Any" type to specified generic type argument

Tags: scala, generics, types, casting

Is it possible to write a generic function that accepts a value of type "Any" and a  generic type argument say "T" and return Option[T] by checking runtime type of the value passed in ?

I tried in repl (Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66))

```
def cast[T](x: Any): Option[T] = x match {
case v: T => Some(v)
case _ =>  Option.empty[T]
}
```

I get the warning :

```
 warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case v: T => Some(v)
```

How do i some how pass in the class type and do explicit type checking instead of generics ?

P.S. obviously due to type erasure the above code blows up. Sample repl interaction :

```
scala> val x :Any = 123                                                                                    
x: Any = 123                                                                                               

scala> cast[Int](x)                                                                                        
res0: Option[Int] = Some(123)                                                                              

scala> cast[String](x)                                                                                     
res1: Option[String] = Some(123)                                                                           

scala> val x :Any = "dfg"                                                                                  
x: Any = dfg                                                                                               

scala> cast[Int](x)                                                                                        
res2: Option[Int] = Some(dfg)                                                                              

scala> cast[Int](x).get                                                                                    
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer                         
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)                                          
  ... 33 elided
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `ClassTag` for the runtime type:

```
def cast[T: ClassTag](x: Any): Option[T] = x match {
  case v: T => Some(v)
  case _ =>  Option.empty[T]
}

println(cast[Int](1))
println(cast[Int]("hello"))
```

Yields:

```
Some(1)
None
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.
further reading :
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: Note that this has limitations: `val list = List("a", "b") ; cast[List[Int]](list)`

Comment: @MichaelZajac Indeed. I'll expand the answer soon to be more general.

Comment: @MichaelZajac if my understanding is correct the problem is due to the second level type nesting, wrapped in the List's (or any wrapped data type's constructor).